# how to config route for another environments in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have problem when running another environments.

For example: my url follow 
`demo.com/speech`, but another url follow `demo.com/mav`.

In my localhost, it's done. But another host, it's hash code.

I assign `$prefix = '/speech' or '/mav'` in file `routes.php`.

```
$prefix = '/speech/';
Route::get('{prefix}/auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

But in file blade, I don't know anyway to call `route()` with `$prefix`.

What can I do, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

To use `route` helper you need to name your route like so:

```
 Route::get('{prefix}/auth/login', [
       'as'     => 'login',
       'uses'  => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'
 ]);
```

Then in your view to generate URL

```
route('login', ['prefix' => 'speech']);
```

Comment: <code>Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix], function()
{
    $prefix = 'speech';
 Route::resource('user', 'UserController', [ 'names' => [
        'index'   => $prefix + '.user.index',
 ]]);
});</code>
<br/>
`'index'   => $prefix + '.user.index' `not working,